# how to establish connection between peers in peer js

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, peerjs, simple-peer

My aim is connecting `webrtc` peers and sharing their video, but I'm not able to connect peers in the below code.

```
const [stream, setstream] = useState();
const myVideo = useRef();
const userVideo = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then((currentStream) => {
            myVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream;
            setstream(currentStream);
        });
}, []);

var peer1 = new Peer({ initiator: true, stream: stream, wrtc: wrtc });
var peer2 = new Peer({ wrtc: wrtc });

peer1.on('signal', (data) => {
    peer2.signal(data);
});

peer2.on('stream', (stream) => {
    console.log('connected');
});
```

I know this will not work so how can I connect peers with `id`? Please help me in this problem.

Comment: In order to make 2 peers communicate, you have to have a peer server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example in the [PeerJS API documentation](https://peerjs.com/docs.html#api) shows how to connect two peers. I would recommend you start there; if you get stuck again, don't hesitate to update your question and I'll try assist you further.

<sup>I would have written this in a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.</sup>